# New users can't see Apple applications from Utilities folder in Launchpad

Tags: macos, terminal, launchpad, defaults, utilities

I felt like giving my mess of Launchpad icons a fresh start. So I did

```
defaults write com.apple.dock ResetLaunchPad -bool true && killall Dock
```

On checking Launchpad, it had appeared to have reset itself to default layout. Then to stop it resetting again on every reboot, I did

```
com.apple.dock ResetLaunchPad -bool false
```

It's always worked in the past but now I've discovered that no applications in /Applications/Utilities appear in Launchpad anymore. Terminal, Activity Monitor, AppleScript Editor and all the rest are missing:

[image: Where's Terminal! Ahhh!!]

The ones you see here actually reside in just /Applications. But Utilities are supposed to populate here amongst them.

The problem is persisting across users and also when I create new users.  I find that very odd in and of itself because I did not use `sudo` or otherwise elevate the commands I used to set the `ResetLaunchpad` flag.

Basically, I don't want to have to drag the apps in /Applications/Utilities to the Launchpad icon and then manually organise them back into Launchpad's "Other" folder every time I create a new user.

Any ideas how I might be able to get Launchpad to behave normally again? Thanks! I'm using OS X 10.9.5.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is a related cause and the potential fix but I was able to get the issue resolved for me.

I use [Homebrew Cask](http://caskroom.io) and I have it setup to symlink the applications from my Homebrew Cask directory into my /Applications/ folder (the default is ~/Applications).

The solution for me was to remove all of the Symlinks (I just moved them to my desktop) and then I ran the terminal command:

`defaults write com.apple.dock ResetLaunchPad -bool true; killall Dock`

After doing this my Utilities folder showed back up and when I moved the symlinks back into my Applications folder everything was back to normal.

If you do have symlinks in your /Applications/ directory or maybe even aliases it's probably worth giving this process a try.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I tested it for myself. As you say Utilities stop showing in LP when symlinks to apps exist - not only in /Applications/Utilities but in /Applications as well. After moving them to the desktop, running the command again fixed it. This one was truly beyond me. Thank you.